# Using offset and collections in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have never used collections but thought it might be the best option for me. I'm trying to run a loop through cells in a column (B). If the value is "THIS" or "THAT", I'd like the program to look to the next column (C) and store the value (integer) in a collection. Next I would need to compare the collection to a list found within another workbook. For each collection that is not in the new workbook, I would like the collection value to be pasted in Column G of the new workbook. Here's what I came up with.

```
Sub StoreCartusResNumsAsCollection()
Dim coll As New Collection
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Sheet2.Range("A2:A52")
    If c.Value = "CARTUS" Then Offset(1,0) coll.Add c.Value
Next c
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To coll.Count
Debug.Print coll(i)
End Sub
```

The code does not yet include the "OR" part for checking if the value is the "THAT" piece. I also have not gotten past adding to the collection as I was trying to debug.print to ensure the collection worked but stalled out.

Comment: (1) From your description it sounds like `Sheet2.Range("A2:A52")` should be `Sheet2.Range("B2:B52")` (2) `If c.Value = "CARTUS" Then Offset(1,0) coll.Add c.Value` should be `If c.Value = "CARTUS" Or c.Value = "THAT" Then coll.Add c.Offset(0, 1).Value` (3) If you edit your question to just ask why this current "adding to the collection" piece isn't working, then it would make it a good question and I could put this as an answer, but at the moment it sounds like you are asking for help with the rest of the code too, which makes it too "broad" to be a good question.

Comment: My A column definitely was supposed to be B as you stated and the modification to the If statement helped make it work. (Also needed "Next i" after the debug line. This was all I was actually wanting help with as I think I can get the rest. I just wanted to give the full scope of what I was trying to do. Thanks for the help.